# CSS: unit relative to the container, not viewport?

Tags: css

CSS has units that are relative to the viewport: vw, vh, vmin, vmax.

Is there anything in CSS that I can use to determine the size of an element's container? For example, say I have:

```
<div>
   <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```

I would like to apply styles to the `p` tag that are relative to the container's size (the `div` in this case). Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `%` ?

Comment: Not yet but they are in the spec. https://css-tricks.com/container-units-should-be-pretty-handy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they exist but you still need to wait for too long before using them.

From [the Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-3/#container-lengths)

> Container query length units specify a length relative to the dimensions of a query container. Style sheets that use container query length units can more easily move components from one query container to another.

Find the relevant github discussion here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5888